# GUI Test Automation for Embedded Systems

Tags: gui-test-framework

I am looking for a GUI Test Automation framework for testing GUI on low level embedded system.
The GUI will be developed in Peg Pro, I want to automate the GUI flow and test the system and GUI.

Please suggest some frameworks to explore